# Is there a approximate string comparison function which is odd like mathematical functions are odd?

Tags: algorithms, functions, string-matching

I say odd like a mathematical function, a mathematical function is odd if

```
f(-x) = -f(x)
```

I understand that comparing two strings may seem to have little to do with this, because the arguments cannot be negative, but I mean that the functions value should be the negative of it's value with swapped arguments, i.e.,

```
distance(str2, str1) = -distance(str1, str2);
```

Comment: Well, you could use `distance(a, b) = length(a) - length(b)`, which is *very* fuzzy and fulfills your requirement.

Comment: This property is called "antisymmetrical". It's usually used only with boolean values (f(a,b) IFF !f(b,a)), but it's a straightforward generalization to extend this to mean f(a,b) == -f(b,a).

Comment: @KilianFoth Right. I remeber from my Quantum Physics course, An antisymmetrical wave function represents fermions which is where the Pauli Principle of Exclusion comes from. I just didn't remember the term in english but it turns out it's the same in spanish *antisimétrica*.

Comment: > I understand that comparing two strings may seem to have little to do with this, because the arguments cannot be negative – Actually they have a lot in common! Indeed “replace number x by -x” and “replace pair of string (a,b) by (b,a)” are two examples of involutions on the respective sets! Looks like your math intuition works well. :D For the record the generalisation of “odd” in this setting is “equivariant” for the given group operations.

Comment: BTW distance is not the best name one could dream of for a possibly negative number, what about *signed_distance* or *algebraic_distance* ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with *any* string distance function.

For example, consider the following distance function:

```
distance(a, b)
{
    return calc(a, b);
}
```

If you make the order of the arguments significant, then you can invert the sign of the result as needed:

```
distance(a, b)
{
    var first = getFirstAlphabetically({a, b});

    var isNegative = (a != first);
    var sign = isNegative ? -1 : 1;

    return calc(a, b) * sign;
}
```

Keep in mind this is just pseudocode.

Comment: So in c, I could use `strcmp()` to determine the sign ... Nice, why didn't I think of that, It must be that I am losing my ability to think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a lot of them!  This is just the theory of *even* and *odd* part of functions adapted to this context.

Take any function *h* defined on pair of strings and set *ĥ(a,b) = h(b,a)*. Then the **odd** and **even** part of *h* are respectively *h- = (h - ĥ)/2* and *h+ = (h + ĥ)/2*.

Now, if you take any function *h* defined on pair of strings, then its *odd* part *h-* suits your requirements. Furthermore you obtain every interesting function this way, because if *h* is odd then it is its own odd part *h = h-*.

It might also be fun to remark, as @MetaFight did, that given any odd function *u* which only takes the values *1, 0* and *-1*, then the multiplication by *u* turns an odd function into an an even function and conversely!